# Ruby 1.9.1 'socket' module

Tags: ruby, sockets

I have a problem with writing simple chat app.
Everything was working, and suddenly I got this:

```
test.rb:3:in `<main>': uninitialized constant UDPsocket (NameError)
```

I wrote some test-code to figure out what's the problem`

```
require 'socket'

socket = UDPsocket.new 'localhost', 4900
```

And I still got this error (even from this simple code)

I work on Ubuntu 10.04 and Ruby 1.9.1 (installed by apt) and my irb version is 0.9.5.
And funny thing, but on irb it seems to work just fine.
I've seen some question 'bout that and apparently most people haven't any problems with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is called `UDPSocket` with a capital `S`.